# Play Sound Representing Numbers

Tags: java, swing, audio, timer, javasound

I'm having an issue trying to play sound representing a generated number.

I'm able to play the first number but for some reason the following numbers no sound comes out.

currently I have a button that tests for each individual number which sets the sound.

code as follows: **EDITED**

```
String s = tTo.getText();
            String t = tFrom.getText();
            try {
                int x = Integer.parseInt(t);
                int d = Integer.parseInt(s);
                if (x >= d) {
                    JOptionPane
                            .showMessageDialog(f,
                                    "START value is higher or Equal to END value, please enter a lower number...");
                }
                rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * (d + 1 - x) + x);
                // rn1
                if (rand1 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 % 10 == 0) {
                    rn1 = 0;
                    index4 = 1;
                    call1 = "C:/FortuneApps/Randomiser/0.wav";
                } else if (rand1 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 % 10 == 1) {
                    rn1 = 1;
                    index4 = 6;
                    call1 = "C:/FortuneApps/Randomiser/1.wav";
                } else if (rand1 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 % 10 == 2) {
                    rn1 = 2;
                    index4 = 11;
                    call1 = "C:/FortuneApps/Randomiser/2.wav";
                } else if (rand1 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 % 10 == 3) {
                    rn1 = 3;
                    index4 = 16;
                    call1 = "C:/FortuneApps/Randomiser/3.wav";
                } else if (rand1 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 % 10 == 4) {
                    rn1 = 4;
                    index4 = 21;
                    call1 = "C:/FortuneApps/Randomiser/4.wav";
                } else if (rand1 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 % 10 == 5) {
                    rn1 = 5;
                    index4 = 26;
                    call1 = "C:/FortuneApps/Randomiser/5.wav";
                } else if (rand1 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 % 10 == 6) {
                    rn1 = 6;
                    index4 = 31;
                    call1 = "C:/FortuneApps/Randomiser/6.wav";
                } else if (rand1 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 % 10 == 7) {
                    rn1 = 7;
                    index4 = 36;
                    call1 = "C:/FortuneApps/Randomiser/7.wav";
                } else if (rand1 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 % 10 == 8) {
                    rn1 = 8;
                    index4 = 41;
                    call1 = "C:/FortuneApps/Randomiser/8.wav";
                } else if (rand1 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 / 10 % 10 == 9) {
                    rn1 = 9;
                    index4 = 46;
                    call1 = "C:/FortuneApps/Randomiser/9.wav";
                }
```

And so on for each random number.

So that all works fine as it gets the first number right every time. and also displays a picture representing the number.

I also have a timer to play the sound:

code as follows: **EDITED**

```
timer8 = new Timer(20, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            index9++;
if (index9 == 50) {
                timer8.setDelay(20);
                if (rand1 >= 100000) {
                    try {
                        as1 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                                call1));
                        c1 = AudioSystem.getClip();
                        c1.open(as1);
                    } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException
                            | UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
                        JOptionPane
                                .showMessageDialog(f, "Sound has Failed");
                    }
                    c1.start();
                } else if (rand1 >= 10000) {
                    try {
                        as2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                                call2));
                        c2 = AudioSystem.getClip();
                        c2.open(as2);
                    } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException
                            | UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
                        JOptionPane
                                .showMessageDialog(f, "Sound has Failed");
                    }
                    c2.start();
                } else if (rand1 >= 1000) {
                    try {
                        as3 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                                call3));
                        c3 = AudioSystem.getClip();
                        c3.open(as3);
                    } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException
                            | UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
                        JOptionPane
                                .showMessageDialog(f, "Sound has Failed");
                    }
                    c3.start();
                } else if (rand1 >= 100) {
                    try {
                        as4 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                                call4));
                        c4 = AudioSystem.getClip();
                        c4.open(as4);
                    } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException
                            | UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
                        JOptionPane
                                .showMessageDialog(f, "Sound has Failed");
                    }
                    c4.start();
                } else if (rand1 < 100) {
                    try {
                        as5 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                                call5));
                        c5 = AudioSystem.getClip();
                        c5.open(as5);
                    } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException
                            | UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
                        JOptionPane
                                .showMessageDialog(f, "Sound has Failed");
                    }
                    c5.start();
                } else if (index9 == 100) {
                    if (rand1 / 10 >= 10000) {
                        try {
                            as2 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                                    call2));
                            c2 = AudioSystem.getClip();
                            c2.open(as2);
                        } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException
                                | UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,
                                    "Sound has Failed");
                        }
                        c2.setFramePosition(0);
                        c2.start();
                    } else if (rand1 / 10 >= 1000) {
                        try {
                            as3 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                                    call3));
                            c3 = AudioSystem.getClip();
                            c3.open(as3);
                        } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException
                                | UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,
                                    "Sound has Failed");
                        }
                        c3.setFramePosition(0);
                        c3.start();
                    } else if (rand1 / 10 >= 100) {
                        try {
                            as4 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                                    call4));
                            c4 = AudioSystem.getClip();
                            c4.open(as4);
                        } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException
                                | UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,
                                    "Sound has Failed");
                        }
                        c4.setFramePosition(0);
                        c4.start();
                    } else if (rand1 / 10 < 100) {
                        try {
                            as5 = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(
                                    call5));
                            c5 = AudioSystem.getClip();
                            c5.open(as5);
                        } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException
                                | UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,
                                    "Sound has Failed");
                        }
                    }
                    c5.setFramePosition(0);
                    c5.start();
                }
 //and so on for each digit
                    timer8.stop();
                }

            }
        }
    });

    timer8.setInitialDelay(5);
}
```

so in the first part of the code call is a string that finds the audio file on my pc.
I don't get how it only plays the first number but none of the others.
at first I thought maybe the sound was to close together so i set delay longer but that didn't change anything.

**EDITED**

timer8 is started at the end of my timer7 (timer7 displays the last image representing the number)

here's what I'm trying to do once the numbers are displayed a clip will play saying congratulations number: 1 , 2 , 3

currently all of got is congratulations number: 1 (following numbers not working)

I have tried other numbers first 0 through to 9 and the all work as the first number.

I've changed the size of the number from 6 digits to 2 digits and still only plays the first number.

any help would great.

Comment: You do notice the code duplication here right?

Comment: yes but I thought maybe that's holding the problem

Comment: I grew up with Java but I'm not into it anymore, but clearly someone else will point you to the right direction and answer it ;)

Comment: As mentioned in the other comment there is a ton of code duplication. Perhaps you should try to whittle it down to the shortest possible repro and post that code instead. Going thru the process may actually expose your problem and is a common troubleshooting step. As it is right now many people are not going to be inclined/able to answer you.

Comment: Do you ever call `timer8.start();`?

Comment: yes at the end of my timer7 sorry forgot to add that

Comment: I'm Going to try put the audio in different timers and see if that works

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok guys it seems that Java doesn't like calling multiple Clips in the same timer when I split the 6 clips up into 6 different timers it works perfectly fine. I bit more coding but works:)

Comment: Late coming on here, but yes, each audio file has to be played in its own thread if you want them to sound concurrently and don't use a mixer such as TinySound.